# Connect a UIProgressView to a UIWebView - Swift/Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview, uiwebview, swift

I've got a `UIWebView` on my **storyboard**, loading a page from my blog.
I'd like to put also a `UIProgressView` there... but I don't really know how to connect that to my **Web View**.

Can you help me?
PS: My main project is in **Swift**, but if you have a solution working with **Objective-C**, post it anyway and I'll try to convert it :)
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thy this out in swift 3

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = NSURL(string: "https://topdigital.agency")
    let request = NSURLRequest(url: url as! URL)
    webView.loadRequest(request as URLRequest)
    webView.delegate=self

}

func webViewDidStartLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {

    self.progressView.setProgress(0.1, animated: false)
}


func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {

    self.progressView.setProgress(1.0, animated: true)
}

func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, didFailLoadWithError error: Error) {

    self.progressView.setProgress(1.0, animated: true)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Answer (score -1):

One way is to use the `UIWebViewDelegate`. Just set the `webview.delegate = self`. The `UIActivityIndicator` will be in the right corner of the `UINavigationBar`. If you have no navigation bar, you can just set a position for the `UIActivityIndicator` and call `activityIndicator.stopAnimationg()` to stop the animation.

```
func webViewDidStartLoad(webView: UIWebView) { //start
    var activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .White)
    var activityBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: activityIndicator)
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = activityBarButtonItem
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
}

func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) { //stop
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil
}
```